# Audio in IE cuts off when locking the phone

Tags: lumia

I've been having this weird issue with my Nokia Lumia recently. Every time I lock my phone while watching a YouTube video, it turns the audio off and makes it impossible to keep listening to the audio with the locked screen. It used to be different -  I was able to lock the screen off and the keep the audio playing. Surprisingly, it happens only with the audio I lists to in my IE App. When listening to podcasts or music in my Podcast App, locking the screen  doesn't stop the audio from being played. I haven't done any system updates recently so I have no clue what might have caused that change.

Comment: What phone and what version of the OS do you have?

Comment: Have your tried using any youtube apps such as this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/tube-pro-best-client-for-youtube/9wzdncrfhvhw

Comment: I believe this is the expected behavior. When your phone is locked, the browser should not be running.

Comment: it's a browser not a media player...